# How can I Refresh Web View in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a webview as tab A and a todolist flatlist on tab B. If the user adds an entry to the flatlist on tab B, i want the tab A webview to refresh.

I couldn't find any `.refresh()` or `reload()` methods on the webview control https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: there is no direct approach using WebView, you will have to wrap it up inside ScrollView and use refreshControl prop

Answer (score 25):

You can set a key to the webview

```
key={this.state.key}
```

and then you can reload it by updating the state

```
this.setState({ key: this.state.key + 1 });
```

Answer (score 21):

Well I reload **WebView** by doing following:

```js
render() {
  let WebViewRef;
  return (
    <View style={Style1.container}>
      <WebView
        ref={WEBVIEW_REF => (WebViewRef = WEBVIEW_REF)}
        source={{ uri: this.state.site }}
        renderLoading={this.ActivityIndicatorLoadingView}
        startInLoadingState={true}
      />
      <Button title="Reload Me!" onpress={() => { WebViewRef && WebViewRef.reload(); }} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

In this code I Declare Reference Variable `WebViewRef` first then assign this to `WebView` as `ref={WEBVIEW_REF => (WebViewRef = WEBVIEW_REF)}` and then call this reference for `reload()` as `()=>{ WebViewRef && WebViewRef.reload();}`

Answer (score 17):

The [`react-native-community/react-native-webview`](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) component has a [`.reload()`](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#reload) method on the `ref`.

```tsx
const webViewRef = useRef();
// ...
return (
    <WebView ref={(ref) => webViewRef.current = ref} ... />
)
// ...
```

You can then use the following to reload:

```tsx
webViewRef.current.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

Reload was not working on my end.

If you want to refresh on focus change you can use the hook useFocusEffect of react navigation and in the unmount clean the URL used in the webview. Then in the initialize you need to set that again. Maybe using a a useState.

```js
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      setUrl(url!);
      return () => {
        setUrl(undefined);
      };
    }, [url]),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a dummy query parameter to signal a refresh of the web view:

In Tab B, I dispatch a change which changes "latestItemId" in the global state. 
In Tab A, I use mapStateToProps which maps to `<WebView source={{uri:URL?latestItemId=${latestItemId}}} />` in the render method. This causes it to think it's a new url and reload it.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I have `source={{html}}` so `refresh()` won't work in that situation.  However, in my case I am still able to inject javascript so I can set some properties specifically `document.styles.body.color` to match dark and light mode.

```
  const fg = colorScheme === "light" ? "black" : "white";
  const webViewRef = createRef<WebView>();
  useEffect(() => {
    webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(`
      document.body.style.color='${fg}';
      true
    `);
  }, [fg]);

...
  <WebView
    ref={webViewRef}
    originWhitelist={["*"]}
    style={{
      height: 200,
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
    }}
    onMessage={() => {}}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    injectedJavaScript={`
      document.body.style.color='${fg}';
      true;`}
    source={{ html }}
  />
```